# Is it correct to say "in which to", "from which to", "on which to", etc.?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I see these kinds of phrases used sometimes in articles and books, and they sound weird to me. Here are some examples:

> This is a great environment **in which to** read and work.

> The book offers many fascinating perspectives **from which to** look at society.

> The book offers a ton of profound principles **on which to** base your decisions and actions.

Are these correct?

Comment: You have split the sentences wrongly: This is a great environment in which {to read and work.} -- The book offers many fascinating perspectives from which {to look at society.} -- The book offers a ton of profound principles on which {to base your decisions and actions.} The "to" belongs to the infinitive. Compare This is a great environment in which {I can study}, etc.

Comment: Nothing remotely 'weird' about them.

Comment: So are they correct?

Comment: The OP was probably taught that a relative clause should have a finite verb. An answer should explain when this is not the case.